# User thinks their question was closed when it wasn't

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, banners

At [A subset of $\Bbb R^p$ is open iff it is the union of a countable collection of open balls](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676601/a-subset-of-bbb-rp-is-open-iff-it-is-the-union-of-a-countable-collection-of) the OP complained:

> Well lemme just say that marking this as a duplicate is a little unfair..

But the post wasn't marked as a duplicate, so I tried to reassure him.  It transpired that he sees some banner on the page that I can't see, either when logged in or not logged in:

> - @Ishfaaq Your post has not been marked as a duplicate, and so far nobody has voted to mark it as a duplicate. Five votes would be required. – MJD
> - @MJD: So the redirecting link at the top is just an edit?? – Ishfaaq
> - I see no redirecting link. @LuizCordeiro's comment is just a comment, and I think a helpful one at that. – MJD
> - @MJD One which says this question may have an answer elsewhere with a link to a previous question?? – Ishfaaq
> - I don't see anything like that on this page; I have refreshed it several times. There is a link I can click to close the question, which suggests that it is not yet closed; the link normally displays the total number of close votes, if there are any, but there aren't any. – MJD
> - @MJD: Okay.. But there is a label on the top of the post which says "This question may already have an answer here".. Maybe its visible just to me. Don't matter as long as the question is not marked duplicate.. – Ishfaaq

Is there some banner that is only shown to OP?  What does it look like? What causes it to appear?

---

User127096 tried a test, and I now see a banner at the top of this question:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: From the answer below it seems that you are right. It is strange since there hasn't been any close votes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you search for duplicates](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3258/how-do-you-search-for-duplicates)

Comment: (not at all, I'm just testing).

Comment: @user127096 The banner appeared; I pasted a screenshot.

Comment: Is the [banners] tag meant to discuss The Incredible Hulk as well?

Comment: @Asaf I think only several of them at once. It is plural.

Comment: @MJD, should we post a link to this meta discussion as a comment so that the OP you were talking to can read it for more information?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- Yes, there is such a banner, visible only to the OP.
- An example of this banner is embedded in the question [Automatic insertion of dupe-banner after just one close vote is vulnerable to abuse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166427/).
- It appears after a duplicate vote or flag has been cast on the question.

Once upon a time, this "pre-closure banner" was visible to everyone, but after the discussion cited above the behavior was changed.

Comment: The "close" link under the article, and the "vote to close" dialog don't mention that there was a previous close vote. Perhaps in this case the vote was cast, then retracted, but the banner remains?

Comment: @MJD Methinks a "close as duplicate" flag. The user who suggested the dupe is below 3k.

Comment: Wow, that is a monumentally stupid behavior. Where do I go to downvote that?

Comment: @HenningMakholm You can propose it be disabled for Math. In the context of Stack Overflow the banner makes sense: their close vote review queue is some 117K questions long, and growing. So the time gap between the first and the last close vote can be pretty long. In the process, the question asker only gets the auto-comment, which they do not necessarily read or understand (reading comprehension can be pretty low among SO users). Having a banner shouting in their face to look at that other question makes sense in this context.

Comment: @user127096: The stupid thing is that the banner is hidden from everyone else but the OP, such that he'll get into confused conversation like the one MJD had. What's the point of making it impossible for people to offer relevant help and guidance to new confused users? There should be _some_ way for established users to discover what it is the OP sees.